# Template class taking itself as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

### Context

The simplified class below is a container of `Chunk<T>`.

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class C = Chunk>
class           ChunksManager
{
  C<T>   *m_origin;
  // ...
}
```

The point of the second template argument is to specify inherited versions of `Chunk`.

### Problem

Now, if i want to call a non-inherited method of `InheritedChunk` in a `Chunk` method (via a method pointer), i need the `InheritedChunk` type.
This leads me to write this :

```
  C<T, C<T> >   *m_origin;
```

Problem here is i can not specify the second template argument endlessly. My thought was that it would work with a default value for the second argument of `Chunk`...

```
template <typename T, typename C>
class           Chunk;
template <typename T, typename C = Chunk<T> >
class           Chunk
```

...but the second argument of the default value is missing (and not declared if i specify C).

I have the same problem when i try with a template template argument :

```
//                           recursive argument here
//                                      v
template <typename T, template <typename> class C>
class           Chunk
```

Is there a way to work around this issue ?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case (the problem to solve) a bit more? I don't understand what you want to achieve with that construct.

Comment: Maybe proxy the default such as `template<typename T> dummy_type { };` and for the default `typename C = dummy_type<Chunk<T>>` and then you can either specialize against it, or SFINAE against it (`std::enable_if` if your're targeting C++11 should come in handy). Basically, your problem is template recursion and to break out of it you need to make C++ see another type entirely.

Comment: Followup thought: You may be even able to specialize so that `template<typename T> class Chunk<T, Chunk<T>>` is equivalent to `Chunk<T, dummy_type<Chunk<T>>>` via `template<typename T> class Chunk<T, Chunk<T>>: Chunk<T, dummy_type<Chunk<T>>> { }`... but not sure.

Comment: I have a `Chunk::iterate` method to which i give an `InheritedChunk` method, but i need the `InheritedChunk` type to use the said method in `Chunk`.

Comment: On second thought, that stuff probably wouldn't work. Just make a sink type like `struct ChunkSelfSink { };` and specialize against that. That would work because there would be no recursive template instantiation. You'd specialize knowing that is equivalent to `Chunk<T>` within the context of `Chunk<T, ChunkSelfSink>`.

Comment: @Sliv Maybe provide a simplified overview of what your actual problem is exactly then? Right off the bat it seems like there's two very simple solutions a) specialize against some kind of unique dummy type peicemeal inline within Chunk, or b) abstract out the stuff that's trying to use the template parameter ` template C` and then, specialize against it. If it's just some sub-types like iterator, either of these approaches should be super easy. A stripped down but accurate example of your problem would help me write an answer.

Comment: @Sliv also, what C++ standard are you targeting here? The answer may be quite different depending on the standard.

Comment: The sink type seems to work, i was just stuck with the recursive problem.

Comment: @Sliv Great. I've really got to stop answering questions in the comment section. I end up getting no credit for it :(.

Comment: @mr.stobbe My question was a bit messy, sorry :/